# Generic List in C# DLL cannot be accessed from CLI

Tags: dll, c++-cli, clr, unmanaged, .net-remoting

Want to preface this by pointing out I am new to C++/CLI

We have one solution with an unmanaged C++ application project(We'll call "Application") and a C# .net remoting project which builds to a DLL(We'll call "Remoting"), and a CLI project for interfacing between the two(We'll call "Bridge").

Everything seems to be working, we have an IMyEventHandler interface in Bridge which successfully receives events from Remoting and can call methods in Application.

```
#ifndef EVENTS_HANDLER_INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED
#include "EventsHandlerInterface.h"
#endif

#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
    DLLEXPORT bool RegisterAppWithBridge(IMyEventsHandler * aHandler);
    DLLEXPORT void PostEventToServer(AppToServerEvent eventType);
    DLLEXPORT void PollEventsFromServer();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

In Bridge implementation we have a method for handling an event and depending on which event type it is, we will call a different method for handling that exact type:

```
void Bridge::OnReceiveServerEvent(IMyEvent^ aEvent)
{
    // Determine event type
    ...
    Handle_SpecificEventType();
}
```

This all is working fine so far. Once we call the handler for a known type of event, we can directly cast to it from the generic interface type. And this is where we start to see the issue. All these event types are defined in another DLL generated from C#. Simple events that have just ints or strings work just fine, but we have this SpecificEventType which contains a list of other types(We'll call "AnotherType") all defined in another DLL. All required DLL's have been added as references, and I am able to gcnew a AnotherType without it complaining.

However, once I try to get AnotherType element out of the list, we see the build error: "C2526 'System::Collections::Generic::List::GetEnumerator' C linkage function cannot return C++ class"

```
void Bridge::Handle_SpecificEventType(IMyEvent ^evt)
{
    SpecificEventType ^e = (SpecificEventType ^)evt;

    // We can pull the list itself, but accessing elements gives error
    System::Collections::Generic:List<AnotherType ^> ^lst = e->ThatList;

    // These all cause error
    array<AnotherType ^> ^arr = lst->ToArray();

    AnotherType ^singleElement = lst[0];

    for each(AnotherType ^loopElement in lst){}
}
```

To clarify why we're doing this, we are trying to take managed events defined in a C# DLL and sent through .net remoting from a newer C# server, and "translate" them for an older unmanaged C++ application. So the end goal is to create a copy of the C# type "SpecificEventType" and translate it to unmanaged "SpecificEventType_Unmanaged" and just make a call to the application with that data:

```
// Declared in Bridge.h and gets assigned from DLLEXPORT RegisterGameWithBridge method.
IMyEventsHandler *iApplicationEventHandler;

// Bridge.cpp
void Bridge::Handle_SpecificEventType(IMyEvent ^evt)
{
    ... Convert SpecificEventType to SpecificEventType_Unmanaged
    iApplicationEventHandler->Handle_SpecificEvent(eventUnmanaged);
}
```

This messaging all seems to be working and setup correctly - but it really doesn't want to give us the elements from the generic list - preventing us from pulling the data and building an unmanaged version of the event to send down to the application.

I hope I have explained this well, again I am new to CLI and haven't had to touch C++ for some years now - so let me know if any additional details are needed.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was because all the methods in Bridge implementation were still inside of an extern "C" block. So much time lost - such a simple issue.